# How to handle errors after message has been handed off to QueueChannel?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-amqp

I have 10 rabbitMQ queues, called event.q.0, event.q.2, <...>, event.q.9. Each of these queues receive messages routed from event.consistent-hash exchange. I want to build a fault tolerant solution that will consume messages for a specific event in sequential manner, since ordering is important. For this I have set up a flow that listens to those queues and routes messages based on event ID to a specific worker flow. Worker flows work based on queue channels so that should guarantee the FIFO order for an event with specific ID. I have come up with with the following set up:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow eventConsumerFlow(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate, Advice retryAdvice) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(
                    Amqp.inboundAdapter(new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(rabbitTemplate.getConnectionFactory()))
                            .configureContainer(c -> c
                                    .adviceChain(retryAdvice())
                                    .addQueueNames(queueNames)
                                    .prefetchCount(amqpProperties.getPreMatch().getDefinition().getQueues().getEvent().getPrefetch())
                            )
                            .messageConverter(rabbitTemplate.getMessageConverter())
            )
            .<Event, String>route(e -> String.format("worker-input-%d", e.getId() % numberOfWorkers))
            .get();
}

private Advice deadLetterAdvice() {
    return RetryInterceptorBuilder
            .stateless()
            .maxAttempts(3)
            .recoverer(recoverer())
            .backOffPolicy(backOffPolicy())
            .build();
}

private ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy() {
    ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(1000);
    backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(3.0);
    backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(15000);

    return backOffPolicy;
}

private MessageRecoverer recoverer() {
    return new RepublishMessageRecoverer(
            rabbitTemplate,
            "error.exchange.dlx"
    );
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWorkers; i++) {
        flowContext.registration(workerFlow(MessageChannels.queue(String.format("worker-input-%d", i), queueCapacity).get()))
                .autoStartup(false)
                .id(String.format("worker-flow-%d", i))
                .register();
    }
}

private IntegrationFlow workerFlow(QueueChannel channel) {
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from(channel)
        .<Object, Class<?>>route(Object::getClass, m -> m
                .resolutionRequired(true)
                .defaultOutputToParentFlow()
                .subFlowMapping(EventOne.class, s -> s.handle(oneHandler))
                .subFlowMapping(EventTwo.class, s -> s.handle(anotherHandler))
        )
        .get();
}
```

Now, when lets say an error happens in `eventConsumerFlow`, the retry mechanism works as expected, but when an error happens in `workerFlow`, the retry doesn't work anymore and the message doesn't get sent to dead letter exchange. I assume this is because once message is handed off to QueueChannel, it gets acknowledged automatically. How can I make the retry mechanism work in `workerFlow` as well, so that if exception happens there, it could retry a couple of times and send a message to DLX when tries are exhausted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want resiliency, you shouldn't be using queue channels at all; the messages will be acknowledged immediately after the message is put in the in-memory queue;if the server crashes, those messages will be lost.

You should configure a separate adapter for each queue if you want no message loss.

That said, to answer the general question, any errors on downstream flows (including after a queue channel) will be sent to the `errorChannel` defined on the inbound adapter.

Comment: Thanks Gary, this is what I have thought, since it's clearly written in documentation, that if message is handed over to another thread or placed in in-memory queue, it gets acknowledged automatically when ack mode is AUTO. I thought maybe there is another way around this. but it seems that the only way will be flow/inbound adapter per queue.

Comment: You can use MANUAL ack mode (and ack or reject messages - to send them to the DLX), but you could end up starving one or more process because the prefetch count applies across all queues (with the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`; with the `DIrectMessageListenerContainer`, a consumer (or consumers) are dedicated to each queue, so the prefetch count won't be an issue there.

Comment: I have tried this approach and it is working fine if there are no errors during message conversion. If there is an exception in `messageConverter`, the flow doesn't add additional headers like `amqp_channel` and `amqp_deliveryTag`. I could work arround this by doing message conversion in a transformer.

Comment: Well, a message conversion error occurs before there is an, errr..., `Message<?>` - since those headers are added to the message by the converter, there is a catch-22 - there is no message yet. We could, I suppose, add those headers directly to the `ErrorMessage` (since there is no `failedMessage` property). Open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues) and we'll take a look, if you want us to explore it.